# ¿es posible leer los campos que posee una vista en SQL server desde C# webform?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

¿Es posible obtener los encabezados de una vista en SQl server desde un formulario C#, y mandar estos nombres a un textbox separado por comas? por ejemplo:

¿cómo se llamaría esto que trato de hacer para investigar?

```
camposSQL = LeerVista: "vw_VistaNombre"

this.textbox.text = camposSQL;
```

con la guía de @reekeecast actualizo el código que llevo (aun no funciona sólo devuelve el primer registro):

```
string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnString"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection viewViewer = new SqlConnection(constr);
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE, IS_NULLABLE FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE table_name = @viewName", viewViewer);

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@viewName", txtVista.Text); 
            viewViewer.Open();
            var resultadoColumnas = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
            lblamposVista.Text = Convert.ToString(resultadoColumnas);            
            viewViewer.Close();
        }
```

Comment: Depende de tu base de datos y/o del proveedor que usas para conectarte desde C#. Por ejemplo, en ADO.NET, existe `conn.GetSchema(...)`. Puedes hacer búsqueda también en cuanto a "table metadata" o "information_schema"

Comment: Ok, ya se que no estoy loco y es posible, voy a revisar con estas pistas que encuentro. Gracias compa!

Comment: Puede ser algo como `SELECT * FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name = 'vw_VistaNombre'`

Comment: @reekeecast Eso es compa!!! añádela como respuesta para marcarla por favor. Muchas gracias!

Comment: Si se puede hacer pero vas a tener que crear un datatable para leer los encabezados con los campos y luego ir agregándolo, en las cajas de texto correspondientes vas a usar mucha programación mas que SQL, espero que te ayude